# Error assembling 'push [ebp+12][edi][esi]'

Tags: windows, assembly, masm, 32-bit

I can't figure it out what I am missing here. It's obvious that the bug starts at `read_matrix` procedure but I don't understand why.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;includem libraria msvcrt.lib, biblioteca.asm si declaram ce functii vrem sa importam
includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit:proc
extern printf: proc
extern scanf:proc
extern fopen:proc
extern fclose:proc
extern fscanf:proc
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;declaram simbolul start ca public-de acolo incepe executia procramului
public start
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;sectiunile programului, date, respectiv cod
.data
operation dd 0
message db "Introduceti o operatie cu matrici:",10,0
msgA db "A=",0
msgB db "B=",0
msgR db "Rezultat:",0
format db "%s",0
format1 db "%d",0
read_mode db "r",0
write_mode db "w",0
fileA dd 0
fileB dd 0
rezultat dd 0
op1 dd "A+B",0
op2 dd "AB",0
op3 dd "aA",0
op4 dd "A-B",0
op5 dd "detA",0
matA dd 80 dup(?)
    dd 80 dup(?)
nrcolA dd 0
nrlinA dd 0
pointerA dd 0
pointerB dd 0
pointerR dd 0
.code
;functie de afisare mesaj pt introducerea operatiei pe matrici
afisare proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp ; pregatim stack frame-ul
    mov eax, [ebp+8] ; citim primul argument de pe stiva
    push eax
    call printf
    add esp,4
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 4 ; salt inapoi la adresa de return, si curata parametrii de pe stiva
afisare endp
;functie de citire a unei operatii pe matici, ulterior folosita pt citire cale fisier
citire_operation_file proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp ; pregatim stack frame-ul
    mov edi, [ebp+8] ; citim primul argument de pe stiva-format
    mov esi,[ebp+12];citim al doilea argument de pe stiva-operatie/fisier
    push esi
    push edi
    call scanf
    add esp,8
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 8 ; salt inapoi la adresa de return, si curata parametrii de pe stiva
citire_operation_file endp
;functie de deschidere a unui fisier
open_file proc
     push ebp
     mov ebp, esp ; pregatim stack frame-ul
     mov edi, [ebp+8] ; citim primul argument de pe stiva-format
     mov esi,[ebp+12];citim al doilea argument de pe stiva-operatie/fisier
     push esi
     push edi
     call fopen
     add esp,8
     mov esp, ebp
     pop ebp
     ret 8 ; salt inapoi la adresa de return, si curata parametrii de pe stiva
open_file endp
close_file proc
     push ebp
     mov ebp, esp ; pregatim stack frame-ul
     mov edi, [ebp+8] ; citim primul argument de pe stiva-format
     push edi
     call fclose
     add esp,4
     mov esp, ebp
     pop ebp
     ret 4 ; salt inapoi la adresa de return, si curata parametrii de pe stiva
close_file endp
read_matrix proc
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp ; pregatim stack frame-ul 
        ;[ebp+8]=pointerA,[ebp+12]=matA,[ebp+16]=nrcol,[ebp+20]=nrlin,[ebp+24]=format
        ;citesc nr de linii pt matricea 
        push [ebp+20]
        push[ebp+24]
        push [ebp+8]
        call fscanf
        add esp,12
        ;citesc nr de coloane pt matrice 
        push [ebp+16]
        push[ebp+24]
        push[ebp+8]
        call fscanf
        add esp,12
        ;citesc matricea 
        ;parcurg cu edi nr de linii,initial acesta este 0
        mov edi,0
        et_loop:
           cmp edi,[ebp+20]
           ja urm
            ;parcurg cu esi nr de coloane,initial acesta este 0
             mov esi,0
               et_loop1:
                 cmp esi,[ebp+16]
                 ja urm1
                 push [ebp+12][edi][esi]
                 push [ebp+24]
                 push [ebp+8]
                 call fscanf
                 add esp,12
                 inc esi
               loop et_loop1
              urm1:
              inc edi
        loop et_loop
        urm:
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret 20; salt inapoi la adresa de return, si curata parametrii de pe stiva
read_matrix endp
start:
           ;afisez de afisare a unei operatii cu matrici
           push offset message
           call afisare
           ;apelez funtie de citire a unei operatii cu matrici
           push offset operation
           push offset format
           call citire_operation_file
           ;afisez mesaj de introducere cale fisier pt matricea A
           push offset msgA
           call afisare
           ;citesc calea fisieruli pt matricea A
           push offset fileA
           push offset format
           call citire_operation_file
           ;deschid fisierul pt matricea A
           push offset read_mode
           push offset fileA
           call open_file
           mov pointerA,eax
           ;citesc matricea A
           push offset format1
           push offset nrlinA
           push offset nrcolA
           push offset matA
           push pointerA
           call read_matrix
           ;afisez mesaj de introducere cale fisier pt matricea B si retin pe stiva pointerul de fisier
           push offset msgB
           call afisare
           ;citesc calea fisierului pt matricea B
           push offset fileB
           push offset format
           call citire_operation_file
           ;deschid fisierul pt matricea B si retin pe sitiva pointerul de fisier
           push offset write_mode
           push offset fileB
           call open_file
           mov pointerB,eax    
           ;afisez mesaj de introducere cale fisier pt rezultat si retin pe stiva pointerul de fisier
           push offset msgR
           call afisare
           ;citesc calea fisierului pt rezultat
           push offset rezultat
           push offset format
           call citire_operation_file
           ;deschid fisierul pt rezultat si retin pe sitiva pointerul de fisier
           push offset write_mode
           push offset fileB
           call open_file
           mov pointerR,eax  
           ;inchid fisierul pt matricea B
           push pointerB
           call close_file
           ;inchid fisierul pt matricea A
           push pointerA
           call close_file
           ;inchid fisierul pt rezultat
           push pointerR
           call close_file
           ;terminarea programului
           push 0
           call exit
end start
```

The assembler is giving me an error on this line:

```
push [ebp+12][edi][esi]
```

But why is this an error? The syntax seems okay to me.

Comment: You need to be more specific than that.  Why do you believe this is not working?  How do you expect it to behave?  What does it actually do?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there an error message, or what is the bug?

Comment: It seems to be here  "push [ebp+12][edi][esi]". But why? Because the syntax seems ok.

Comment: `push [ebp+12][edi][esi]` is not a valid addressing mode in x86. See this document for the supported ways of addressing memory. https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/V22.0201-002/addressing_modes.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As David Hoelzer and Michael Petch said, `[ebp+12][edi][esi]` isn't a valid addressing mode. If it were a valid addressing mode it would be the same as `[ebp+12+edi+esi]` which is not what you want. You're trying to push the address of an element of a matrix and the address calculation is significantly more complicated than that.

You'll need to replace it with code that calculates the correct address. Something like:

```
mov eax, edi          ; row
imul eax, [ebp+16]    ; row * nrcol
add eax, esi          ; row * nrcol + col
mov edx, [ebp+12]     ; matrix address
lea eax, [edx+eax*4]  ; element address
push eax
```

Also the following code probably doesn't do what you intend it to:

```
matA dd 80 dup(?)
    dd 80 dup(?)
```

This allocates space for an 160 element matrix, not a 6400 element (80x80) matrix. If you want the later you should use:

```
matA dd 80*80 dup (?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving an error because the `[ebp+12][edi][esi]` notation is not valid.  Honestly, I'm not really sure what you're intending to do with it.  Here are the ways `PUSH` can be used:

```
Registers:
   PUSH AX
   PUSH EAX
   PUSH RAX

Immediate:
   PUSH 0xFFFF
   PUSH 0xFFFFFFFF
   PUSH 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Indirect (Memory):
   PUSHW [BX]   ;16 bits - I don't believe an 8 bit push is permitted.
   PUSHL [BX]   ;32 bits
```

Using AT&T syntax some of this may be clearer.  For instance, `push $0xffff` to push an immediate or `push 0x1234` to push memory contents.

With the indirect or memory pushes, you may use other registers to address them.  You may find a reference like [this](http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/push.htm) helpful.

**Note that some of this may need refinement since I'm talking from memory.  I don't think I've ever actually used a `PUSH` of the content of a memory address.**